# How to change yolo bounding style from (x,y,w,h) to (x,y,w,h,a)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, bounding-box, yolo

I'm training **yolo** model, I have the **bounding boxes** in this format(x,y,w,h,a)=>ex (197.996317 669.721413 390.070453 29.258397 7.696052) the "a" is the angle of the bounding box , I want to implement the **angel** to bounding box format and train the yolo network

I already calculated bounding box and his angle but I don't know how to implement that to the yolo network style.

How can I implement angle to yolo bounding box style?

Answer (score 0):

Well 60 images is really not - You dont have enough combination - explaining why u need to retrain.

Read this here https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects
It also applies to the original repository.